# ASP.NET and The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, cocoahttpserver

I'm making an httpwebrequest using a public Root authority Certificat file X509.  I only have the public key,  not the private key.  Everything works fine from a Console app but it does not work from an asp.net app.  I get the error: "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

The option to disable Validation is not an option.

**Here is the code**

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxxxxx/gateway.aspx");
string post = "abcdef";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentLength = post.Length;

var cert = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(@"c:\temp\root.cer");

req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
stOut.Write(post.ToString());
stOut.Close();

HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

**Here is the System Logs from System.Net and System.Net Sockets.**

System.Net Information: 0 : [5928] SecureChannel#8106798 -  A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.

System.Net Information: 0 : [5928] SecureChannel#8106798 - Remote certificate was verified as invalid by the user.

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [5928] Socket#7486778::Dispose()

System.Net Error: 0 : [5928] Exception in the HttpWebRequest#51319244:: - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

System.Net Error: 0 : [5928] Exception in the HttpWebRequest#51319244::EndGetRequestStream - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

**Further info**

If I use this code (from CodeGuru)

```
  public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender,
     X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,
     SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
  {
     if (sslPolicyErrors ==
        SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) {
        return false;
     } else if (sslPolicyErrors ==
        SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch) {
        System.Security.Policy.Zone z =
           System.Security.Policy.Zone.CreateFromUrl
           (((HttpWebRequest)sender).RequestUri.ToString());
        if (z.SecurityZone ==
           System.Security.SecurityZone.Intranet ||
           z.SecurityZone ==
           System.Security.SecurityZone.MyComputer) {
           return true;
        }
        return false;
     }
     return true;
  }
```

I ultimately get the error:

> Remote Certificate Chain Error

Answer (score 13):

This problem can be fixed with this added to Application_Start:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

It basically allows for a mismatch between the server and its certificate.

Source:

http://www.ben-morris.com/asp-net-web-services-and-ssl-certificates-establishing-a-trust-relationship

**Note: This workaround is not recommended for production**

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the issue could be what is posted on this [link](http://www.ben-morris.com/asp-net-web-services-and-ssl-certificates-establishing-a-trust-relationship). The ASPNET worker process requires the cert name to match the server name. There are work arounds that can be implemented with test environments.

For certificate generation you can use a free program called SelfSSL.exe with commands such as:

`SelfSSL.exe /T /N:CN=localhost /V:999 /Q`  (where "localhost" is cert name)

And:

`winHTTPCertCfg.exe -g -c local_machine\my -s localhost -a Administrators` (to grant admins access to the cert)

Comment: The root.cer has been added to the LocalMachine Store using the MMC snap in .  
Ive also attempted to use winhttpcertcfg.exe to no avail. Since I do not have a private key , nor do I have a PFX file.  Thoughts?

Comment: The test environment is not using SSL so that is ok.

I was planning on using the Root certification from the CA but that may be part of the issue. I suppose then that the SSL setup on 
server end is a bit dodgy.